# How to make text bold that function got as parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a text bold by using a function which gets the text as a  parameter, here is my code:

```
    <script>
    function font(b) 
    {
    b.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    alert(b);
    }
    </script>
    <input onclick="font('aaaa');" type="button" value="Font (1)">
```

My problem that I'm not getting the desired response, though without `b.style.fontWeight = "bold";` it alerts "aaaa".

I don't see what is the problem here, I tried to put the parameter in a variable and then change its property but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: `alert` cannot render HTML. alerts should only be used to show some simple messages.

Comment: You're passing a string to your function. Strings don't have a `style` property. Trying to access it returns `undefined`, and trying to access `fontWeight` of `undefined` causes an error which stops your script. That's why you don't see the alert box.

Comment: true though why my teacher than gave me that??? his mistake???  
 1.make function that gets text as parameter and makes it bold/italic/underline, 
 2.make function that will sum numbers that it got as parameter(that one is easy)

Answer (score 1):

Create an input field where you'll write your text and create a button which will change the font-weight of the text. After that attach an event listener to the button. When you click the button your font will change to bold.

working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4kzsq2tb/

HTML

```
<button id="font-button">
change font to bold
</button>

<input id="input-field" type="text"/>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('font-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inputField = document.getElementById('input-field');
  font(inputField);
})


function font(b) {
  b.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}
```

Comment: Apparently not. I still don't understand how you got from OP's post to an `<input type="text"/>`, and this answer lacks the explanation of the key point that one needs to pass an HTML element to the function as opposed to a string but it seems to have satisfied OP nonetheless.

Comment: OTOH OP just posted an answer that does something different entirely, so who knows?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="c"></div>


    <input onclick="font('aaaa');" type="button" value="Font (1)">
    <script>
        function font(b) 
    {

    document.getElementById('c').style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById('c').innerHTML=b;
    }
    </script>
```

works fine function gets text as parameter and makes it bold, well makes div style bold not text itself as guys said u cant make text or variable bold